# Is there any C# analogue of C++ std::is_same class template?

Tags: c#, c++, generics, equality, type-traits

In C++ someone can write the following piece of code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type1, typename Type2>
bool TestArgumentTypesOnEquality(Type1 argument1, Type2 argument2)
{
    return std::is_same<Type1, Type2>::value;
}
```

`std::is_same` class template checks whether `Type1` and `Type2` (which are the types of `TestArgumentTypesOnEquality` function template arguments) are equal.

Is there any C# generics analogue of this C++ standard library functionality?

```
public static bool TestArgumentTypesOnEquality<Type1, Type2>(Type1 argument1, Type2 argument2)
{
    return /* ??? */;
}
```

Of course there are only simple test samples. Real code is more complicated. In fact I only want to know is it possible to test two generic type parameters on equality in C#.

Comment: `typeof(Type1) == typeof(Type2)`?

Comment: @juharr OK. And what about compile-time mechanism?

Comment: Generics are not templates.  So, they are not changed at compile time.  And I'm not sure if you want what I mentioned or maybe `argument1.GetType() == argument2.GetType()`  the difference would be that calling `TestArgumentTypesOnEquality(1, (object)2)` would be true for `GetType`, but false for `typeof`.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I understand it. I wanted just what you mentioned. But... Sadly that there is no compile-time mechanism. Generics themselves are an example of compile-time mechanism, aren't they?

Comment: No, when you compile something with generics it doesn't do replacements like templates.  It creates something that has metadata that indicates that there are type parameters.  Check out this link that discusses it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? What's wrong with `if (typeof(Type1) == typeof(Type2)) ...`?

Comment: @juharr OK. Thank you for your link.

Comment: @usr Nothing is wrong in fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# doesn't have many compile time features, such as templates, macros, `static_assert`. C# generics are almost runtime. C++ templates are absolutely compile time. The compiler time type determination mechanism like `std::is_same`, `std::enable_if` won't work in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can make decisions based on reflection objects:

```
if (typeof(Type1) == typeof(Type2)) ...
```

Normally, generic code is meant to not know and not care about anything concrete about the types. You can deviate from that rule if circumstances warrant it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C++ but there are two types of equality in C# - object (reference) equality and value equality. Value equality checks the underlying value of the properties of a struct, and Reference Equality checks the "pointer" of the reference type to see if they are pointing to the same object reference.

To check to see if two objects are the same Type (but not the same reference or same value) use Assert(object1.GetType() == object2.GetType())

Comment: You cannot pass objects to `typeof` only type names and generic type parameters.  If you have objects then you'd want `object1.GetType() == object2.GetType()`.

Comment: Oops - good spot, and good correction. Curse my hasty typing.